# Could i use node module with react

Tags: reactjs, node-apn

Could i use node module with react. 
Could i use [node-apn](https://github.com/node-apn/node-apn) module directly in my react project to push notifications?

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot use this package at client side (in browser) - it is intended to be run in node.js server environment.

Although some of the npm packages that are isomorphic can be run both client and server side.